# Is it possible to access JSF 2 non shared resources from shared resource

Tags: jsf-2

Is it possible to access non shared resources (web application resources XHTML / CSS ) from shared resource which is packaged as JAR file and placed inside WEB-INF/lib folder.

Eg. 
App 
--views 
---layout 
----template.xhtml

--WEB-INF 
----lib 
------jar1 
--- ----META-INF 
----------resource 
------------views
--------------index.xhtml

In the above structure can index.xhtml reuse template.xhtml? I wanted to have application specific template rather than using it from shared template.

Comment: Did you tried to access? Did you tried anything? And if you tried and have some errors than post those errors.

Comment: Corrected my original question as mentioned wrong path for couple of files. 

I have figured out the problem and solved it by providing full relative path starting from app context. <br> Eg. provided template=views/layout/template.xhtml instead of template=layout/template.xhtml in index html 
<br>
@partlov thanks for your quick response

Comment: You should provide an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Partlov,

As I mentioned earlier, Have solved by providing relative path starting from app context rather then from current folder. 
In facelet tag declaration have used `template=/views/layout/template.xhtml` instead of `template=layout/template.xhtml` in `WEB-INF/lib/jar1/Index.xhtml`

@BalusC, Thanks for your note. I do agree your comment.